# how can I create a trigger in SQL Server to update after insert in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I created a trigger that after insert must update the table inserted:

```
   alter trigger DispararInsertFactura1
   on FacturaCabecera
   after insert
  as
  BEGIN
     Declare @numfac int;
    select @numfac = NumFactura
                 FROM FacturaCabecera
                 WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) from FacturaCabecera);
          update FacturaCabecera 
         set NumFactura=@numfac+1
          where Id = (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED);

  END
  GO
```

But doesn't work, Did I make a mistake?

Comment: "Doesn't work" Is never a good description of what your problem is

Comment: What's it do?  Do you get an error?  What's the error?

Comment: when I create the trigger, does not give me any error but not update the field after the insert in the table, when I insert in the table I have a field that is NULL, the tigger must update with a number which is @numfac+1

Comment: What does this query return for you?  Is it NULL?:   SELECT NumFactura FROM FacturaCabecera WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) FROM FacturaCabecera)

Comment: Triggers operates on sets so generally doing something like `where Id = (SELECT Id FROM INSERTED);` might not work as expected as the inserted virtual table might hold more than a single row.

Comment: Why don't you use an identity column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not allowed for a trigger to start a separate access to the same table it is defined on. The table is right smack in the middle of being altered (otherwise referred to as *mutating*).

"After" triggers are good for audit-type actions. Inserting an entry into a different table to describe the action that just took place.

"Before" triggers are good for verifying and possible altering the data stream before it goes to the table. This is what you want to do.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have "Before" triggers. It does, however, allow "Instead Of" triggers on tables. These triggers are not executed as part of the DML operation but before it begins. As the name implies, the trigger is executed in lieu of the DML operation. The trigger itself must initiate the operation or nothing happens. Defining an "Instead Of" trigger that does nothing is a good way to render a table or view read-only.

```
alter trigger DispararInsertFactura1
on FacturaCabecera
instead of insert as
    declare @numfac int;
    select Top 1 @numfac = NumFactura
             from FacturaCabecera
             order by id desc;

    insert into FacturaCabecera( ..., NumFactura, ...)
        select ..., IsNull( @numfac, 0 ) + 1, ...
        from Inserted;
```

Notice that the trigger itself must execute the Insert statement, allowing it to alter what is being inserted.

Comment: thank you, it work how I want... but I changed my code that I showed you at first, instead to put  
                 

                 select @numfac = NumFactura
                 FROM FacturaCabecera
                 WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) from FacturaCabecera);

To get NumFactura I put: 

                 WHERE id = (@id-1);

It work too but I don't know if its correct, I prefer you answer

Comment: This is a bad idea. Just use an `IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking in this and I found the mistake, I didn't realize that the MAX number always would be a value NULL because the trigger will updated after of inserted in the table, (the value is NULL when I insert) so I changed this:

```
select @numfac = NumFactura 
                 FROM Factura Cabecera 
                 WHERE id = (SELECT max(id) 
                 from Factura Cabecera);
```

for this that give me the number max second:

```
SELECT @numfac = NumFactura FROM FacturaCabecera WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(id) 
                 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2) id FROM FacturaCabecera where    
                tipofactura='1' ORDER BY id DESC) T);
```

Thanks for you help

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TRIGGER DispararInsertFactura1
on FacturaCabecera

INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
DECLARE @numfac int;
SELECT TOP 1 @numfac = NumFactura
FROM FacturaCabecera
ORDER BY id DESC;

INSERT INTO FacturaCabecera( __ , NumFactura, __)
SELECT  __ , IsNull( @numfac, 0 ) + 1, __
FROM Inserted;
```

Trying this